# How to calculate equivalent width of absorption line?

Tags: python, width, linear-regression, equivalent

I have 3 arrays of `x`, `y`, and `sigma` values. I fit the best line through my data points using `numpy.polyfit` function and the `numpy.polyval` function. I then normalized my data by dividing the `y`-values by the best fit `y`-model. How do I calculate the equivalent width of the spectral line?

The equation for equivalent width is:

[image: equation for equivalent width]

Where `F_lambda/F_0` is equal to my normalized data points (`y/ymodel`).

Comment: I've no idea of the topic, but after searching the terms in your question I came across this [Python4Astronomers 1.1 documentation](http://python4esac.github.io/core/scipy_fft.html#the-synthetic-line) which contains this line of code:`np.trapz(1-spec_line,x=wavelengths) # trapezoidal integration`, which suggests the [numpy.trapz()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.trapz.html) function may be useful?